# Excel VBA - Pasting values from a dropdown selection in a column

Tags: excel, vba

```
For i = 1 To 20
If Target.Address = "$B$15" Then
  If Target.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeAllValidation) Is Nothing Then
    GoTo Exitsub
  Else: If Target.Value = "" Then GoTo Exitsub Else
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    Newvalue = Target.Value
    Application.Undo
    Oldvalue = Target.Value
      If Oldvalue = "" Then
        Target.Value = Newvalue
      Else
        If InStr(1, Oldvalue, Newvalue) = 0 Then
            Target.Value = Oldvalue & ", " & Newvalue
      Else:
        Target.Value = Oldvalue
      End If
    End If
  End If
End If
Worksheets("DropDowns").Cells(i + 7, 26).Value = Newvalue
Next i
```

I am having problems with the following part of the code:

```
Worksheets("DropDowns").Cells(i + 7, 26).Value = Newvalue
```

The code above it enables a list drop down menu to have multiple selections, I am trying to paste the selection into a cell and then paste the new selection in the cell below it and on until no more selections are made. However, what it's currently doing is pasting the selection and then pasting the second selection over the first, then third over second etc.
[Drop down menu selection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LuivR.png), [What is being pasted](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eOyur.png), [What I am wanting pasted](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YRSfx.png)

Comment: A screenshot of the "before" and "after" would be useful here.  It's not clear why you're doing the undo/redo 20 times when there's only one cell you're monitoring.

Comment: What is your use-case?  Can you use a List Box Form Control instead of a Drop-Down Cell Validation?

Comment: There is the option to select numbers from 1 through 20, whether it be one number, five numbers or all twenty.

Answer (score 0):

This should do what you want:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim Oldvalue, Newvalue, arr, rngList As Range
    
    If Target.Address <> "$B$15" Then Exit Sub
    If Target.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeAllValidation) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    
    Set rngList = Worksheets("DropDowns").Cells(8, 26)
    
    If Len(Target.Value) = 0 Then
        rngList.Resize(20, 1).ClearContents
        Exit Sub
    End If
        
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    Newvalue = Target.Value
    Application.Undo
    Oldvalue = Target.Value
    
    If Oldvalue = "" Then
        Target.Value = Newvalue
    Else
        If InStr(1, Oldvalue, Newvalue) = 0 Then
            Target.Value = Oldvalue & ", " & Newvalue
        Else
            Target.Value = Oldvalue
        End If
    End If
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    
    'update the list of values
    With rngList
        .Resize(20, 1).ClearContents
        arr = Split(Replace(Target.Value, " ", ""), ",") 'remove spaces before splitting
        .Resize(UBound(arr) + 1, 1).Value = Application.Transpose(arr)
    End With
      
End Sub
```

FYI it's best not to use `:` to put multiple statements on one line - it can get confusing quickly, particularly inside `If` blocks.

Comment: I was able to fix the issue by getting rid of the For loop and adding Worksheets("DropDowns").Cells(Rows.Count, 26).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0) = Newvalue before the last End If